# Is it allowed to do Musafaha with one hand?

Tags: hadith

Bismihi Ta'ala.

Today, I met with a man and did musafaha with one hand as I had a bag in another hand.

He told me: "Put down your bags on the floor and do musafaha with two hands."

I told him:  "Is not it permissible to do musafaha with one hand?"

He told me: "There is no evidence in hadith to do musafaha with one hand."

I told him: "As far I know, it is allowed. Do you have any evidence of doing musafaha with two hands?"

He told me: "Yes. In the time of Prophet (SM ), If anybody comes to Prophet (SM) and wants to do musafaha with one hand, he denies him. If you want to see my evidence, please bring your evidence also."

Now, I am in need of evidence of doing musafaha with one hand.

If it is not allowed, tell me and prove by hadith.

Otherwise help me by giving evidence for opposite.

Jazakallah.

Comment: To be fair, the burden of proof is on the one with the claim, not on you.

Comment: Instead of giving people help and evidence on how to answer on certain questions, the one questioning should take a course in logic, fiqh and usul al-fiqh. I find at least 3 logical fallacies in his arguments.

Comment: Shaking hands is a cultural matter and not religious.  The Arabs did it but it does not mean a Muslim must also do it.  In Africa, some tribes spit on each other as praise and it's perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bismillah,

Greeting your Muslim brother and shaking hands is from the Aadab of Islam آداب الإسلام .And while I've not come across any hadith that supports your friend's statement:

> "Yes. In the time of Prophet (SM ), If anybody comes to Prophet (SM)
> and wants to do musafaha with one hand, he denies him."

I've read this Hadith that was narrated by Imam **At-Tabarany** (Imam **Al-Albany** **did not** state this Hadith as a weak Hadith):

> إن المؤمن إذا لقي المؤمن فسلم عليه وأخذ بيده فصافحه تناثرت خطاياهما
> كما يتناثر ورق الشجر
>
> “When a believer meets another believer and he greets him with
> Salam and takes him by his **hand** and shakes hands with him, their sins
> will fall like the leaves of a tree.”

Now, I know that in some Madhahib, like Al-Madhhab Al-Hanafy, they prefer to use both hands when shaking hands, almost every single Desi brother in our community does that (I live in USA by the way).

However, you will find in the Seerah of the Prophet (PBUH) that in some situations the Prophet (PBUH) used his both hands to teach the Sahabah something, whether individually or in a group. For individuals, Ibn-Mas'oud narrated that the Prohphet (PBUH) taught him the Tashahud (for the prayer) while his hand was between **both** of the Prophet (PBUH) hands.

Allah knows best!

Comment: It was a helpful answer for me. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Well i found a clear [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/92806) saying that Musafaha is and was generally  understood as **the hand shaking by one hand** based on ahadith like this one in [Sahih al-Bukahri](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/79/37) or [Sunan abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/440) or [Sunan ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/33/47). 
This might also be indicated by this hadith which was qualified as da'if from [Jami' at-Tirmdidhi](http://sunnah.com/urn/677960).

But to make it clear -and as it is described in the fatwa mentioned above- it's not bida' at all to use both hands, which is the preferred opinion about shaking hands according to some scholars from Maliki and Hanafi school!
 As some Tabi' a-Tabi'yn used to do so!
 But the statement of the man you met doesn't seem to have a real back-up unless the hadith used by Hanafi and Maliki scholars to support their opinion, but who isn't really related to the act of [shaking hands](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/79/39).

And Allah knows best!